# Accessing data property of IContextualMenuItem

Tags: spfx, fabric

The documentation for the fabric IContextualMenuItem say the data property can be 'Any custom data the developer wishes to associate with the menu item'.

How does one access that data in the item's onClick handler using react in an SPFX webpart?

Answer (score 0):

i didn't realize there was a second parameter to the onclick. that second parameter is the contextual menu item which give you access to the data (and everything else on the item)